# Catch new process event before the main thread starts to run

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process

I am developing an application to monitor **new** running processes **before the main thread starts running**. The problem is that the code below is executed when all threads in the process are loaded and the process is doing its job. I want to do something like the **"sCreateProcessNotifyRoutineEx"** function from **C++** in **C#**. **Please help with this**

**What I have tried:**

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
public extern static int OpenProcess(int access, bool inherit, int pid);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool ReadProcessMemory(IntPtr hProcess, UIntPtr lpBaseAddress, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer, int dwSize, IntPtr lpNumberOfBytesRead);

ManagementEventWatcher processStartEvent = new ManagementEventWatcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace");

public Service1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     processStartEvent.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(processStartEvent_EventArrived);
     processStartEvent.Start();
}

public async void processStartEvent_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
            try
            {
                string processName = e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value.ToString();
                string processID = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value).ToString();
                int pid = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessID"].Value);
                Process p = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
                string wholeFileName = p.MainModule.FileName;
                await AnalyzeStartup(wholeFileName, p);
            }
            catch { }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for dll injection and or probably best to do this from kernel mode, what is it you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm working on a component for the antivirus engine, but I don't necessarily want to use C++ for this, but try in C#. Preliminary process analysis before execution is to ensure safety.

Comment: Usually the way you would do this is, is dll inject Create process and the load win32 api calls, Proxy the calls to that to see what user mode applications are starting and when they are loading modules ect, and you would usually do this from the kernel so it is reliable, and yes this would be unmanaged code and not C#. There has never been a anti virus of any importance written in C#, it just cant do a lot of things that may be needed, or if you can, it would be the wrong tool for the job anyway

Answer (score 1):

If your code started the process, you could start it suspended (or more technically correct, with a suspended main thread).

In this case, since your code is not starting the process, the only reliable way to do this is with system-wide DLL injection. [Detours](https://github.com/microsoft/Detours) is by far the best library to use for this. To use it from C#, you'll probably need to write a non-trivial p/Invoke layer. You could try the [unofficial wrapper](https://github.com/citronneur/detours.net), but this is an extremely complex problem to solve; YMMV.

Comment: You could also have added YOLO And hold my beer :)